# How can I get the value of an attribute called xlink:href of an xml node by using Scala

Tags: xml, scala, svg

How can I get the value of the `xlink:href` attribute in an SVG path using Scala?

Input: `<use style="fill:#4b0082;stroke:#4b0082;" x="57.6" xlink:href="#mbcc2581984" y="307.584"/>`

Output: `#mbcc2581984`

`Node \@ "xlink:href"` doesn't seem to work.

My question is pretty same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542153/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-called-xlinkhref-of-an-xml-node-by-usin), just the language is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer pretty quick, just keeping it here for future use.

This should be `Node \@ "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href"`